# Rewrite dynamic conditional statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, collision-detection

I'm building a grid where a new item must fit in the next available spot. Items can be 3:2 or 2:3, the grid is 12 columns wide.

How can I rewrite this looped conditional statement to remove the hardcoded limit and accepts input of 3:2 or 2:3 (currently x:3,y:2)?

```
        const check = (
            !grid[rowY + 0][columnX + 0] &&  // @TODO: Hard coded limit
            !grid[rowY + 0][columnX + 1] &&  // @TODO: Hard coded limit
            !grid[rowY + 0][columnX + 2] &&  // @TODO: Hard coded limit
            !grid[rowY + 1][columnX + 0] &&  // @TODO: Hard coded limit
            !grid[rowY + 1][columnX + 1] &&  // @TODO: Hard coded limit
            !grid[rowY + 1][columnX + 2]     // @TODO: Hard coded limit
        );
        if (check) {
            openX = columnX;
            openY = rowY;
            found = true;
        }
        return found;
```

[image]

Comment: It would be great to have visibility on your grid Array. It's un clear for me at the moment but you could maybe use the grid Array' length to track the layout e.g `x.length = 3 && y.length = 2`  or `x.length = 2 && y.length = 3`  this way you can tell whether your grid is 3:2 or 2:3

Comment: You could use a dynamic x/y-loop to replace your hard coded conditions, but in the end you have to check the grid somehow. WIth a function prototype like `checkGrid(columnX, rowY, sizeX, sizeY) : bool`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `every` or `some` array method. Given values for `width` and `height`, you can dynamically calculate `check` as follows:

```
const check = !grid.slice(rowY, rowY + height).some( row =>
    row.slice(columnX, columnX + width).some(Boolean)
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very sleek solution, gives me a lot to think about.

Answer (score 2):

For the grid checking you could use loops to iterate over your keys.

If you need to check the whole grid, simply set loop limit to the length of the respective array.

Below is an example with hardcoded limits:

```js
function unknown() {
  const check = (function() {
    var c = true;
    for (let y = 0; y <= 2; y++) {
      for (let x = 0; x <= 3; x++) {
        c = !grid[rowY + 0][columnX + 0];
        if (!c) {
          return c;
        }
      }
    }
    return c;
  })();
  if (check) {
    openX = columnX;
    openY = rowY;
    found = true;
  }
  return found;
}
```

If you are comfortable you can use ES6, you could use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to get prettier code:

```js
var grid = [
  [true, true, true, true],
  [true, true, true, true],
  [true, true, true, true],
  [true, true, false, true],
  [true, true, true, true],
];
var openX = null;
var openY = null;
var found = grid
  .some((x, xi) => {
    return x
      .some((y, yi) => {
        if (!y) {
          openX = xi, openY = yi;
        }
        return !y;
      });
  });
console.log(found, openX, openY);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, your answer gives me insight how to solve the other limits present in the code. As @trincot answer is more sleeker for this exact situation, I accepted his, but thanks a lot, it really helps!